# What is your preferred choice for showing picture galleries?

Tags: java, jquery, photo-gallery

I am using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) for displaying photo galleries on my web sites.
I am also quite happy with it but as I have to extend it a bit (e.g. show a hyperlink in the caption below the image), I thought it is worth to look around what other gallery frameworks are around.

I am looking for non-flash galleries, non-PHP: **JAVA ONLY** and **jQuery** based solutions.

Thanks for your input. I will collect all your feedbacks and update this question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ON the **client** side I recommend the JQuery plugin [LightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).

You can create a gallery from multiple images, and they are all nicely framed in a popup.